# .htaccess не работает

Tags: .htaccess, php

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_value max_execution_time 120
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/page/([0-9]+)$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?category=$1&zapros=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Вообщем когда перехожу на site.ru/category/page/2 то стили и изображения не показываются, что делать?

Answer (score 1):

да все работает, как раз если бы писало ошибку 404, к примеру, то тогда не работало бы. ;) Почитайте еще раз внимательно статью про ЧПУ, там этот нюанс описывается.

Вам нужно во всех шаблонах и выводе в браузер проверить пути стилей и картинок. у вас сейчас все это задано по относительному пути, поэтому и не работает. вам нужно это поправить примерно так:
было:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/screen.css" />
```

стало:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/css/screen.css" />
```

ну и тоже самое с картинками. в первом примере просто при переходе на `site.ru/category/page/2` браузер будет искать `css/screen.css` по пути `site.ru/category/page/2/css/screen.css`

вы это можете увидеть если включите, например, `firebug` и посмотрите откуда оно не может загрузить картинку или стиль.

Comment: Мне теперь по всему сайту пути менять?

Comment: ага. либо дописать немного htaccess чтобы при запросе `*.css` оно его брало из корня сайта как вы index.php вписали. ну и с картинкаим тоже самое...

Comment: поставьте firebug и посмотрите что оно запрашивает и по какому пути. так будет проще оценить что и где менять.

Comment: ага. либо дописать немного .htaccess чтобы при запросе *.css оно его брало из корня сайта как вы index.php вписали. ну и с картинкаим тоже самое... а как это сделать?

Comment: ну к примеру так

      <FilesMatch "\.(htm|php|js|css|htc|png|gif|jpe?g|ico|xml|csv|txt|swf|flv|eot|woff|svg|ttf|pdf|gz)$">
        RewriteEngine Off
      </FilesMatch>

Comment: не проверял, но должно работать ;)